# Contact sharing solutions for all phones

Tags: cross-platform

**Situation**: events, alumni gatherings where lots of people meet and want to share contacts with each other.

**Contacts** include: phone numbers, social accounts (Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, etc.), email, chat (Skype)...

The solution should work almost every device (including feature phones) and should take least effort and time to share.

My **ideal solution**: An app storing your contact info, allows you to select what info to share and who to share with, allows you to share multiple info with multiple people simultaneously. The shared info is saved directly to the phone's storage, or even better, to each of the corresponding service (Facebook to Facebook, Skype to Skype, email to email, etc.).

What is **NOT a solution**: typing (both on paper and on phone).

**Do you have any idea of such solution?**